# calling a jsp file but keeping the same webpage

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to make an automated function to execute a function for few times. Now, I have this:

```
    formulario.action=jspFile.jsp + "?var=" + value;
    formulario.submit();
```

It works fine if I use just one value, but if I use an array containing 2, 3 or more it fails and just execute the last one.
I want to do something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < totalCount; i++){
    formulario.action=jspFile.jsp + "?var=" + completeList[i];
    formulario.submit();
}
```

My problem is that when submit comes, web browser goes to the other jsp file. Can I do that keeping in my first page all time? Just executing others files but not going there.

Comment: Use ajax? Otherwise you're submitting a form as normal. As far a the array goes, you'd either need to pass multiple values as multiple params, or pass a format that can be parsed on the server side and turned in to multiple values there.

Comment: I was asked to do it with java. Do you mean pass as argument the complete array? That's could work... I will try

Comment: Do what with Java? The client side part will have to be not-Java, you can either use Ajax, or possibly an iframe. You can pass multiple params/values using the same param name, although I'm always wary of using non-indexed param names to represent an ordered collection.

Comment: I have to do a webpage in wich you can select a number and a program in java (on server side) creates a file with info about that number.
I resolved my question doing 2 files, one I receive just one argument and on the other one I receive all numbers with: session.getAttribute....
Now I have the problem on keeping on the same webpage on client side.

Comment: And for that you need to use Ajax (or possibly an iframe, but Ajax seems easier).